# Windows: Connect TI-Launchpad to Amazon Web Services

Tags: c, web-services, amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm doing a project in which I am using the TI CC3200 LaunchPad to detect my bedroom's temperature, real-time. I followed all the AWS IOT C SDK to my Windows machine, downloaded the security keys / certificates, and created a new "thing"in my AWS IOT console. However, it's not clear what are the actual steps to run the sample application and truly test the connection of my device to the Amazon cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to not use bare CC3200, at least for the beginning. There are ready to use CC3200 solutions, like MWS (see [here](https://blog.cesanta.com/improved-ti-cc3200-support-in-mongoose-6.4) ), probably you can find something else. But AFAIK MWS (or even [this](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose-iot)) is able to connect AWS.  Later, then you will understand how it works you can decide either continue to use MWS (etc) or rewrite everything from scratch.